# How to create plot with both vertical and horizontal spikelines in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

Plotly offers the option to display a moveable horizontal or vertical "spikeline" by adding `layout(hovermode = "x unified")` or `layout(hovermode = "y unified")` (see [documentation](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-hovermode)). For example:

```
library(plotly)

x <- seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi, length = 100)
y <- sin(x)
fig <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
fig <- fig %>% layout(hovermode = "x unified")
fig
```

creates this plot with a vertical line that follows the cursor:

[image]

I would like to have both the vertical and the horizontal spikeline displayed. Like this:
[image]

I tried to modify the layout like this:

```
fig <- fig %>% layout(hovermode = "x unified") %>% layout(hovermode = "y unified")
# or
fig <- fig %>% layout(hovermode = c("x unified", "y unified"))
# or
fig <- fig %>% layout(hovermode = "x unified|y unified")
```

None of this worked. Would anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: According to https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4755 maybe it's not natively available in `Plotly`?

Comment: Or this [solution](https://codepen.io/p1ho/pen/VdJOZB)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`spikemode`](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#Layout_and_layout_style_objects) with the option `across` in your layout for both `xaxis` and `yaxis`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(plotly)

x <- seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi, length = 100)
y <- sin(x)
fig <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
fig %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(spikemode = 'across'),
         yaxis = list(spikemode = 'across'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see both vertical and horizontal spike lines are shown.

---

If you only want to have the spike lines to your axis, you could use `toaxis` in your `spikemode` like this:

```r
fig %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(spikemode = 'toaxis'),
         yaxis = list(spikemode = 'toaxis'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see this only shows the spike lines to your axis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to share the x-axis hover between two graphs? I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74246323/share-x-axis-hover-from-one-graph-to-another-plotly-r) about this.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the line thickness using across?

Comment: Hi @H.berg, Yes you could use the argument `spikethickness` in the `list` of your axis.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource on 3d plots - I had the same issue and applied the xaxis = list() and yaxis = list() arguments to layout() and it worked well for me.

https://plotly.com/r/3d-hover/

Comment: That's a nice feature. Did you get it work for 2D Scatterplots as well? I tried by using only two dimensions and obmitting the zaxis but that didn't work.