# Share x-axis hover from one graph to another - plotly R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, plotly, r-highcharter

I would like to hover over the `x-axis` of `p1` and for this hover to be shared on the `x-axis` of `p2`.

```
library(plotly)

p1 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy) %>%
  add_lines(name = ~"unemploy")

p2 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~uempmed) %>%
  add_lines(name = ~"uempmed")

p <- subplot(p1, p2)

p
```

For example, if I hover over `June 1992` on `p1`, the hover should also occur on `June 1992` on `p2`.

Is there a way to do this? It would be something [like](https://codepen.io/p1ho/pen/VdJOZB), but with the graphics side by side.

Comment: According to this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2114#issuecomment-535259328), it is at the moment not possible in python and R. Maybe there is a good javascript solution.

Comment: It looks like it's not too difficult to implement using the `highcharter` library. If you're interested in using that library, let me know. I can add answer that shows you how you can create it.

Comment: Hello, @Cat. Could you post an answer with `highcharter` please? Greetings from Brazil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, Highcharts will work as an alternative to Plotly.

Here is a solution to creating two charts side by side with synchronized tooltips regardless of whether you hover on the left or right chart.

[image]

Hey you; greetings from the States! BTW, if you don't spell the tag name (Kat) correctly, SO won't notify me. I just happened to come across your question again.

I ended up having some failsafe code added that will likely only really work if you only have two plots side by side. There is so much data in `economics`, that many times the two tips would be off by up to a year. The extra code just makes sure that they match.

Since I'm sure that using `economics` isn't your end goal, let me know if whatever configuration you're using doesn't work with this code.

I've added a lot of comments to the Javascript coding quoted in `tags$script`. I hope that this information is enough for you to understand what's happening.

There are two different plotting methods in Highcharts for R.

- If you're familiar with Python's Plotly, there are two versions: express and go. That's kind of what happens in R's Highcharts. (`hchart()` is more like express; `highchart()` is more like go)
- If you're not familiar with Python's Plotly, then it's good to know that plots either start with `hchart()` or `highchart()`. They don't work quite the same way.

If you want to learn more about Highcharts for R, [read more about it here](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/).

This answer uses `economics` (as you did in your question), which comes from the library `ggplot2`. The other libraries used in this answer are `highcharter` and `htmltools`. The graphs are set exactly as your question established for Plotly, only they're rendered in Highcharter.

```
library(highcharter)
library(htmltools)

data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')

(hc1 <- highchart(elementId = "myChart") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = economics$date, type = "datetime") %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Unemployed", data = economics$unemploy) %>% 
    hc_tooltip(useHTML = T))

(hc2 <- highchart(elementId = "myChart2") %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = economics$date, type = "datetime") %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Unemployment Duration",
                  data = economics$uempmed) %>% 
    hc_tooltip(useHTML = T))
```

This next chunk of code aligns these two plots laterally and establishes the synchronized tooltip.

```
browsable(tagList(
  tags$script(HTML("
  setTimeout(function() {                               /* using id from div */
    $('#hc_container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
      var chart, point, i, event;
      for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {      /* loop through both charts */
          chart = Highcharts.charts[i];                     /* identify the chart */
          event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); /* find chart coordinates */
                             /* evaluate for synchronization, to address lateral charts */
          event.chartX = (event.chartX + $('[id$=Chart]').width()) % $('[id$=Chart]').width();
          point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); /* get closest point */
          if (point) {                                      /* if point found, tip it */
              point.highlight(e);                           /* trigger tooltip */
          }
      }  /* this code is to ensure the tooltips match */
      var gr = $('div.highcharts-label.highcharts-tooltip');/* collect visible tooltips */
      var gr0 = gr[0].firstChild.firstChild.textContent;    /* collect 1st x-axis tooltip text */
      var gr1 = gr[1].firstChild.firstChild.textContent;    /* collect 2nd x-axis tooltip text */
      if(gr0 !== gr1) {            /* the tips don't match due to data point proximity, fix it */
        var p = Highcharts.charts[1].series[0].points;      /* find all points in chart 1 */
        point = p.find(o => o.category === gr0);            /* get point matching chart 0 tip */
        if(point) {                                         /* if point found, tip it */
          point.highlight(e);                               /* trigger tooltip */
        }
      }
    });
  }, 500);
  Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {        /* reset tooltip */
    return null;
  };
  Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function(event) { /* executes tooltip from trigger */
    event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);    /* capture that event occurred */
    this.onMouseOver();                                    /* show marker */
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);               /* show tooltip */
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); /* show crosshair */
  };
")),
div(id = "hc_container",     # this id is used in the JQuery/Javascript above
    div(hc1, style = 'height:100%; width: 50%; float:left;'), # first plot
    div(hc2, style = 'height:100%; width: 50%; float:left;'), # second plot
    style = "height:100%; width:100%; float:left;"))) # container styles
```

[image]

Comment: OMIGOSH @Kat That’s incredible! :)